# Root finding and automatic differentiation

Tags: derivatives, machine-learning, newton-raphson, backpropagation

Consider the equation $z = f (z, x)$. We would like to find $z^{\star}$
for $f$ such that $z^{\star} = f (z^{\star}, x)$.

One way to do this problem is through naive iteration:
$z^{(k + 1)} = f (z^{(k)},
x)$; stop when $z^{(k + 1)} \approx z^{(k)}$.

A faster way is to arrange the equation as $g (z) = f (z, x) - z$. This
allows us to use Newton's root finding method:
$$z^{(k + 1)} = z^{(k)} - \left( \frac{\partial g (z^{(k)})}{\partial z}
   \right)^{- 1} \cdot g (z^{(k)})$$ Having found $z^{\star}$, let's say
we would like to find the the derivative of some loss function $l$ with
respect to $x$. This can be done as:
$$\frac{\partial l}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial l}{\partial z^{\star}}
   \frac{\partial z^{\star}}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial l}{\partial
   z^{\star}} \cdot - \left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial z^{\star}} \right)^{-
   1} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$$ Let's say we would to do this
using a software package that implements automatic differentiation like
PyTorch or JAX.

Automatic differentiation has a foward pass and a backward pass. In the
forward pass we simply iterate through
$z^{(k + 1)} = z^{(k)} - J (z^{(k)})^{-
1} \cdot g (z^{(k)})$ and save the output of each iteration. In the
backward pass, we evaluate the derivative $\frac{\partial l}{\partial x}$
through each of the iterations we had done in the forward pass. We can
think of this as unrolling the forward pass and passing
$\frac{\partial l}{\partial x}$ from the output to the input.

What I've just described is the standard way automatic differentiation
is used with the backpropagation algorithm. The problem here is that
we need to backpropagate through all the steps we did in the forward
phase. This is not only time consuming, but requires us to store the
outputs of all the iterations since they are needed in the backward
pass.

I was reading this tutorial:
http://implicit-layers-tutorial.org/implicit_functions/, where the
author says, if we do implicit differentiation, then we don't need to
save the intermediate values because the only Jacobian (the term
$\frac{\partial
g}{\partial z^{\star}}$) we need is the Jacobian at the solution point.
This is kind of a big deal because it means if you can reformulate your
function as an implicit function, then the backward phase of the
backpropagation becomes free. My issue is I don't fully understand why
we can avoid backpropagating through the solver by defining the function
as an implicit function. I would appreciate if someone can enlighten me.

Comment: Are you saying that you have the implicit curve $z-f(z,x)=0$. This means that $z=z(x)$, at least locally. Then you want to find a constant $z^*$ such that $z^*-f(z^*,x)=0$ for any $x$?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an equation $u=f(u,v)$. This means that you have an implicit function $g(u,v)=u-f(u,v)=0$, if you assume that the conditions of the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) hold true.

If you pick some $v_0$, then you can try to solve the equation $u=f(u,v_0)$ numerically. Let's assume you find $u_k\approx u^*$, where $u^*$ is the correct solution. As the functions in this context are continuously differentiable, you find that the partial derivatives of $g(u,v)$, at the point $(u_k,v_0)$, are close to their respective partial derivatives at the point $(u^ *,v_0 )$, including those given by the implicit function theorem.

You can find many discussions searching for "(f(u,v)=0) implicit function " on SearchOnMath.